# Alert condition that only shows after large movement in variable "HMAefi". Pinescript v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

When i plot "HMAefi" you will see that the values are often close to zero. I want the variable "w" to only be 1 or -1 when "HMAefi" does a large movement. Since it is volume the volume changes depending on stock and I want a code that works on all stocks. The variable "w" is to find a top/bottom for "HMAefi". I hope somebody can help me.

```
//@version=5
indicator("delete", format=format.volume)
w=0
ValdLangd = input.int(25, minval=1, maxval=2000,  title="Längd")
//Elders force index
efi = ta.ema(ta.change(close) * volume, ValdLangd)
HMAefi = ta.hma(efi, ValdLangd)
if HMAefi < 0 and HMAefi[1] > HMAefi[2]
    w:=1
if HMAefi > 0 and HMAefi[1] < HMAefi[2]
    w:=-1
plot(HMAefi, color=#F44336, title="Elders Force Index")
hline(0, color=#787B86, title="Zero")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that works on everything, you need a user input. Because, how do you define "**close to zero**"? Is 1 close to zero? Is 10 close to zero?

Have a user input to define this distance. Then check if `HMAefi` is greater than that threshold.

```
in_threshold = input.int(100)
is_greater_than_threshold = math.abs(HMAefi) - in_threshold > 0

if (HMAefi < 0 and HMAefi[1] > HMAefi[2]) and is_greater_than_threshold
    w:=1
if (HMAefi > 0 and HMAefi[1] < HMAefi[2]) and is_greater_than_threshold
    w:=-1
```

Comment: you probably wanted "math.abs(HMAefi) - in_threshold > 0". Nonetheless, the answer is correct so I'll top up.